# What android component could make the app process always running like that despite having 0 running services?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdk-2.3

that's an android app that has a widget that displays the current battery percentage and whether it's charging or not ( that's why it needs to be always running to monitor the battery level ).
I forced stop the running process and the widget stoped to display the correct battery percentage for some few minutes untill the app process became LIVE again.

[image]

what's the component used here ? and how the process starts itself again?

Comment: Widgets are typically registered to update with some interval. They will receive a broadcast that will launch the app process if it isn't already started. If you don't use widgets, you can still register for various system broadcasts in your manifest, or use AlarmManager.

Comment: yes, thanks that's a good hint, but the minimum possible update interval value for the widget `updatePeriodMillis` is 30 minutes. I calculated the time that passed since I killed the process until it become live again it took around 10 minutes meaning the app is using another way to relaunch the process and update the widget. I wonder can AlarmManger or BroadcastReciverers still work despite having no services or a process running ?

Comment: `AlarmManager` is working on Android side, isn't killed/dismissed when you are killing your app. personally I've made few years ago a widget which is self refreshing every... well, that depends on time of a day, in the midday it was about 6 minutes, at night  about 20-30. `updatePeriodMillis` set up to 2x most rare interval, just for a case when `AlarmManager` would not trigger refreshing action for some reason

Comment: The timer wouldn’t have started from the time you killed the process. It would have been some multiple from when the widget was first added. Actually, I suspect it’s just an approximate minimum. It might also trigger early in some cases to avoid having to wake up the device to do it.